# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable '<std::string variable>' was corrupted

Tags: c++

I have a function like below into C++ project.

```
double AdjustFeedPrice(const char *aSymbol, double aPrice)
{
    char *inPrice = NULL;
    double outPrice = 0.0;

    if (aPrice > 0.0)
    {
        std::string inPriceLength = std::to_string(aPrice);
        inPrice = new char[inPriceLength.length() + 1];
        std::string lSymbol = aSymbol;
        size_t found = lSymbol.find("JPY");
        if (found != std::string::npos)
        {
            sprintf(inPrice, "%.3f", (aPrice + PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_VALUE));
            outPrice = std::atof(inPrice);
        }
        else
        {
            sprintf(inPrice, "%.5f", (aPrice + PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_VALUE));
            outPrice = std::atof(inPrice);
        }
        delete[] inPrice;
        inPrice = NULL;
        inPriceLength.clear();
    }
    return outPrice;
}
```

From this function, getting below error:
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'inPriceLength' was corrupted.

What is the issue of inPriceLength variable?

After a short googling, not found any solution.

Please let me know if similar solution is there.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your sprintf is doing something wrong, maybe it needs a bigger buffer than provided?

Comment: Check the return value of `sprintf` and compare it to the size of the buffer allocated for `inPrice`.

Comment: Do you use `sprintf` + `atof` to round a number? There would be simpler ways to do this.

Comment: `inPrice = new char[inPriceLength.length() + 1];` -- The old "let me allocate the sprintf buffer so finely and with no room to spare if I'm wrong" almost always fails.  For laughs, make that `new char [100]` and see if that works.

Comment: You are aware that the results of that function won't actually be the exact values that you're `sprintf`ing?

Comment: OT: `inPrice = NULL;` is superfluous, as well as `inPriceLength.clear();`.

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

You might go out of bounds when printing to `inPrice`. Let's say `aPrice` is a decimal number comprised of `n` digits before and `m` digits after the decimal point (+ the decimal point itself).

So `inPriceLength` will have `m + n + 1` characters, thus `inPrice` will have `m + n + 2` characters. Since the last one is intended for the terminating `\0` you are back to `m + n + 1` usable positions. Now 2 problems might arise:

1. The addition of `PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_VALUE` increases the number such that `m` increases
2. You print more than `n` decimal places (more then `aPrice` originally had)

Both will lead to you printing a longer number (with more characters when converted to string) than `aDigit`, thus going out of bounds.

For example in

```
sprintf(inPrice, "%.3f", (aPrice + PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_VALUE));
```

you print `m` digits before the decimal point, the decimal point itself and 3 digits after the decimal point. Making a total of `m + 1 + 3` characters. This will go out of bounds if `n` was less than 3, i.e. if `aPrice` had less than 3 decimal places.

The same goes for

```
sprintf(inPrice, "%.5f", (aPrice + PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_VALUE));
```

just that it goes out of bounds when `n` was less than 5.

---

## Solution (?)

Maybe you can clarify what this program does. To me it looks like you are rounding `aPrice + PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_VALUE` to 3 respectively 5 decimal places. You could achieve this with

```
std::round((aPrice + PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_VALUE) * 1000.0) / 1000.0
```

respectively

```
std::round((aPrice + PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_VALUE) * 100000.0) / 100000.0
```

Unless your numbers are so big or so small that those multiplications would introduce a significant loss of precision. In that case you can use your approach, but with a `std::stringstream` and save yourself the madness of manual memory management.

```
std::stringstream s;
s << std::fixed             // force decimal format
  << std::setprecision(3)   // print only three decimal places
  << 123.4567890;           // print 123.456
s.seekg(0);

double x;

s >> x;                     // parse value back
std::cout << x;
```

---

But in the end floating point numbers are limited and can't represent every real number, so there might be cases where none of those yield precise results.

Comment: you are right.
I would like to round aPrice with PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_VALUE